# Vb.net Wpf Set Rectangle Fill in Listview using Binded Value

Tags: wpf, vb.net, listview, binding, datatrigger

Using a rectangle or some sort of shape I'd like to display the status of a folder in a listview.

`Green` for if the folder is `Active / Exists`

[image: Folder is Active]

And `Red` if the folder is `inactive / Doesn't Exist`

[image: Folder is Inactive]

First, each item in the list view is provided using a binding for each value (Extension ID, Sent Location), and those values come from a dataset getting it's data from a local .mdf file.

Initially i thought of achieving this by using a for loop and looping through each object and determining if each folder exists or not using the System.IO.Directory.Exists command. Honestly i find this to be a bit tedious but might be the best way to go about it so far. I'm also curious if there is a way to achieve this using a data-trigger or something along those lines to make this a bit easier.